# Public API of Signal Chat App to send and receive messages using python

Tags: python, python-requests, signals, webhooks

I want to create a python script which will configure a webhook and then when user send any message to my SIGNAL PHONE NUMBER, I receive notification/response in my python script. Is there any public API or any third party API which provides clear documentation to done this task in python?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.